# Memory management / ownership question?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Do I have this right ...

```
// Reactor.h
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *reactorCore;

// Reactor.m
[self setReactorCore:[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:[self dataFilePath]]];
...

-(void)dealloc {
    [reactorCore release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

I am pretty sure I am doing this right (but just wanted to check). By my way of thinking NSKeyedUnarchiver returns an object it owns, I am then taking ownership via the @property, later I release reactorCore and all is good?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your code is corect. When in doubt you could use [Build and Analize](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/featuredarticles/StaticAnalysis/index.html) in XCode to check for possible leaks.

Comment: Thank you, just wanted to check, coming to Objective-C only recently its taken a while (and a few reads of the memory management docs) to get to grips with how things work ... much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

That's right. The `NSKeyedUnarchiver` method—since it doesn't contain the words `copy`, `new`, or anything like that—will return an autoreleased object, which you need to retain (as you are doing) to keep ownership of it.